# Train and test split for multivariate and multi-step?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, forecasting

Using this [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/), which deals only with multivariate and one step, I have been trying to write a multivariate and multistep code.
Since the code is too long I'm attaching it [here](https://github.com/HudaBou/Pollution/blob/master/Pollution-Code.ipynb) (you'll find the dataset as well in the same repository as well).

The aim of the code is to predict the Pollution values of the next 6 hours.

After preprocessing the data and normalizing it, I have split the data and reshaped it as follows:

```
# split into train and test sets
values = reframed.values
n_train_hours = 365 * 24 * 1 # 5 years data 1 year training
train = values[:n_train_hours, :]
test = values[n_train_hours:n_train_hours+50, :]

# split into input and outputs
n_obs = n_hours * n_features
train_X, train_y = train[:, :n_obs], train[:, :n_out]  # the problem is here 
test_X, test_y = test[:, :n_obs], test[:,:n_out] # and here

# reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], n_hours, n_features))
train_y = train_y
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], n_hours, n_features))
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape)
```

I have a problem with the train_X, train_y, test_X, and test_y, I'm not sure if I have to use `n_out` and `n_obs` instead of `n_out*n_features` and `n_obs` or another alternative since in both cases by using `inverse_transform` on `inv_y`, I get values that are different to the real ones on the dataset:

```
print('predicted: ',inv_yhat)
print('real:' ,inv_y)

predicted:  [  3.04286     7.406884    6.121824  ... -10.307352   -7.0151763
  -3.4667058]
real: [36.       30.999998 19.999998 ... 24.999998 48.       48.999996]
```

Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

using your exact code on my Macbook Pro in PyCharm and Python 3.7.3, I get the following results with same dataset:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
                     pollution  dew  temp   press wnd_dir  wnd_spd  snow  rain
date                                                                          
2010-01-02 00:00:00      129.0  -16  -4.0  1020.0      SE     1.79     0     0
2010-01-02 01:00:00      148.0  -15  -4.0  1020.0      SE     2.68     0     0
2010-01-02 02:00:00      159.0  -11  -5.0  1021.0      SE     3.57     0     0
(8760, 30, 8) (8760, 6) (35005, 30, 8) (35005, 6)
2020-06-22 16:32:21.057171: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-06-22 16:32:21.072767: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fd8396b94b0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-06-22 16:32:21.072780: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
Epoch 1/3
122/122 - 3s - loss: 0.2229 - val_loss: 0.1685
Epoch 2/3
122/122 - 2s - loss: 0.1521 - val_loss: 0.1490
Epoch 3/3
122/122 - 2s - loss: 0.1433 - val_loss: 0.1415
(35005, 6)
(35005, 6)
Test RMSE: 191.383
predicted:  [57.93556  30.241518 41.339252 ... 39.774303 45.738094 49.2507  ]
real: [36.       30.999998 19.999998 ... 24.999998 48.       48.999996]
```

The predicted values I have look a little bit more realistic. Gee, I hope this isn't a processor architecture type issue.

adding additional info pertaining to MinMaxScaler feature_range

[image]

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html

you can write results out to file like this:

```
results = pd.DataFrame(inv_yhat)
results.index = X_test.index
results.columns = ["prediction"]
results.to_csv("prediction_results.csv")
```

Comment: Hi @Jeanpierre, thank you for your response. I've noticed that as well the predicted values change whenever I re-run the code. However, the real data printed doesn't exist I've checked my dataset to verify it but I didn't find it. Do you think it could it be a MinMaxscaler problem?

Comment: I think that's possible, here is some info. Maybe the feature_range is too constrained and needs the full range for one or both axes:

Comment: as for seeing the resulting data, it is just being printed to the screen, you'd have to write that out to a file if you like